# Find duplicates and count numbers at the same time

Tags: excel

I have rows of data that contains numbers from `1 to 15`, however these numbers can be in any sequence. For example here:

> 3  2  1  12  13  5  6  7  9  15  10  8  4  15  11

I know from a visual count these numbers above are all correct; as there are no duplicates, and all the numbers have values from `1` to `15`. An example of a row of data I found to be wrong:

> 3  2  1  12  12 5  6  7  9  15  10  8  4  15

You can see this line has duplicated numbers i.e. `12`, and number `11` is missing, so this row only has 14 elements in all.

However, I have many rows of data and it is impossible to visually check each row. I need to ensure in each row: there are 15 elements; there are no duplicates, and that the row contains values from `1` to `15` and find which rows are faulty to check these against the original paper data.

Is there a command or function that I can use in Excel to make this process easier?

Comment: if anyone can help I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You could find a set of conditions, each of which is true for rows that contain exactly those 15 numbers in any order and then test several of them. For example, if the row is in `A5:O5`:

```
=AND(COUNT(A5:O5)=15,SUM(A5:O5)=120,MIN(A5:O5)=1,MAX(A5:O5)=15,
AVERAGE(A5:O5)=8,ROUND(STDEV(A5:O5),3)=4.472)
```

This will show TRUE for a row that contains the integers 1 to 15 in any order, and is very unlikely (it could very well be impossible - I haven't checked) to show TRUE for a row that contains any different set of integers.

Comment: would certainly cut down the amount of work to just the rows where a math student was trying to mess you around :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the only way 15 positive integers less than 16 can add up to 120 other than by all being different is with duplication, so :

Check there are 15 numbers
Check their total is 120
Check the maximum is 15
Check not negative (nor zero):

> =IF(OR(COUNT(A5:O5)<>15,SUM(A5:O5)<>120,MAX(A5:O5)>15,MIN(A5:O5)<1),"Error","Plausible")

then check for duplication with Conditional Formatting using a rule such as :

```
=COUNTIF($A5:$O5,A5)>1
```

and a distinctive format. Filter to select "Plausible" and then anything with a distnctive format is non compliant.

[image]